# Customizations of minted environment in LaTeX

Tags: minted, python, customize

I'm using `minted` to write Python code in my document. I have two question as follows:

1. Can we reduce `\begin{minted}{python} \end{minted}` into simpler command like `\begin{mtpt} \end{mtpt}`? In fact I can use `\begin{mtpt} \end{mtpt}` and then replace them all by `\begin{minted}{python} \end{minted}` but this way is rather dull.
2. Why the default color of text in my mwe is red rather than green as in `minted` documentation?
3. How can we customize minted to automatically include `>>>` sign as in Python IDLE? I'm now type `>>>` for each line, rather than insert it automatically.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage {minted}
\begin{document}
This is a minted mwe on {Tex}. 
\begin{minted}{python}
>>>light = 'Lumos!'
>>>light*2
'Lumos!Lumos!'
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Please helps me. Thanks

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: After answering your original question, you corrected it to a completely different question. I have restored your original question so that the reader can understand the answer. If you have a new question, ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{>>>#1}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/minted@addcachefile/after}{%
  \IfStrEq*{\minted@style}{default}{%
    \@namedef{PYG@tok@s1}{\def\PYG@tc##1{\color{green}##1}}%
    }{}}
\makeatother

\newminted[mtpt]{python}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{mtpt}
light = 'Lumos!'
light*2
'Lumos!Lumos!'
\end{mtpt}

\begin{mtpt}
def boring(args = None):
pass
\end{mtpt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your helps. I'm sorry to not including the document language encoding, so it raised an error as pointed out in my edited post. Could you please edit your answer, too? Thank you.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{>\/>\/> #1}` would also solve the problem with `vietnam`.